# How do I get touch events without big library

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery, but I don't want to use jquery mobile, because it is so large, and I don't think I need it. All I am trying to do is get a touch event. This is what I've got.

```
 $('#menuButton').on('click touchstart', function(){
  $('#menu').toggleClass('block')
 });
```

It only kind-of works, but seems to be firing twice a lot on my phone. I think I should check for both touchstart and touchend somehow. This needs to work on all types of devices, hopefully. Thanks!

Comment: A touch device would trigger the `click` event as well if you tap on it, won't it?

Comment: The MDN has a nice summary of all touch native and non-native touch-related methods; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Touch. W3C specs are located here; http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/. If you worry so much about size, why still use core jQuery? ;)

Comment: you may be using `.on()` wrong. it should look like this: `.on('click','.element',function(){});`

Comment: Not sure, but maybe calling `e.preventDefault()` will stop the double events. @JakeZeitz He has the correct syntax for binding a handler to multiple events on an element.

Comment: I am pretty sure the 'element' parameter can be omitted.

Comment: ah, then nevermind hah

Comment: You are quite right, sherlock. The `element` parameter is only required when delegating (i.e. binding handlers to elements that will be added dynamically).

Comment: @Allendar: Did you look for [touch events#Handling clicks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Touch_events#Handling_clicks)?

Comment: That page confirms my guess that proper use of `preventDefault()` is the key.

Comment: @Bergi No :), I didn't really do research. I just wanted to point out where the OP can find the native possibilities for touch event/handling. If I did more research I would've researched until that point and write an answer. Don't have time for that now sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behold! The lifecycle of a touch:

1. your finger hits the glass -> touchstart!
2. your finger leaves the glass -> touchend!
3. your finger it lingers -> click!

Now the lifecycle of a mouse click:

1. your finger depresses the button -> mousedown!
2. your finger it removes pressure from the button -> mouseup!
3. your finger it lingers -> click!

If you are listening for both touchstart and click, the event will fire once on mouse or trackpad computers, and twice on touch devices as you are listening for 2 events in the lifecycle.

If you really want to use click for desktops and touchstart of touch devices (a good idea in many cases), you can do something like this:

```
 var clickEvent = (isMobile)?'touchstart':'click';
 $('#menuButton').on(clickEvent, function(){
   $('#menu').toggleClass('block')
 });
```

How you go about finding `isMobile` is another story.

---

update : I've written a handy script for detecting mobile, if your interested its [npm `isMobile`](https://npmjs.org/package/ismobile)

Comment: Okay, that is all very useful, and I am using modernizr, so i can detect weather touch is available and so forth, but how do I detect if a touchstart and touchend happened on the same element?

Comment: `$(elem).on('touchstart', fun...` and `$(elem).on('touchend', fun...`. Or if you want them to do the same thing `$(elem).on('touchstart touchend', fun...` just like normal. Just be aware of the lifecycle and what it is you are listening for, and whether or not it necessarily implies other events.

Comment: No, that's wrong. At least `mouseup` comes before `click`, and I'm quite confident that it's similar with touch events. You can test by `$(document).on("click mousedown mouseup", function(e){console.log(e.type)})`

Comment: @Bergi really! Let me check that out.

Comment: Be careful with this approach... There are now plenty of laptops with touchscreens (Chromebook Pixel, Asus Ultrabooks, so many others) on the market. On these machines, if your "isMobile" determination is based mainly on feature tests for touch support, you could use this approach, and touchscreen laptops will only bind a touch event. Then when someone uses the laptop's trackpad to click your button, no touch events fire, you've got a completely broken UI.

Comment: So, in most cases, you'll want to just bind both, and use e.preventDefault() to stop the click event from firing a second when touchstart (or touchend, a better parallel to click IMO) has fired before click. Ref: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touchandmouse/